# Plotting multiple rose diagrams from different length lines

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with length and orientation of lines.  I wish to plot rose diagrams of the orientations at length intervals of 2000m.  My lengths go from 98m to 18000m.  I do not use MATLAB often - only for very simple things such as plotting a rose diagram of the entire region.  I am really lost when it comes to loops. 
This is the what I have for the entire region.  But I want it broken up into 10 plots.  I can do this piece by piece but that will take me quite a while since I have to do this for several text files.

```
length=faults(:,4);
theta=faults(:,3);
radians=pi*theta/180;
rose (radians,60);
view(90,-90)
```

Thanks heaps!

EDIT: To better clarify: I wish to extract lines between 0-2000, 2000-4000. 4000-6000, etc.  And for each of these intervals plot the orientation.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use a `for` loop, see Mathwork's documentation on [Flow Control](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f4-1931.html). I'm not sure what your `faults` variable is, so I cannot give a complete example. Also, what do you need the variable `length` for? Anyway, this is roughly how you could proceed with the `for` loop:

```
thetas = ...;              % matrix of thetas
for i = 1:size(thetas,2)
    theta = thetas(:,i);
    radians=pi*theta/180;
    rose (radians,60);
end
```

Comment: thanks... I need the length variable.  I have lengths that vary from ~100 to ~18000.  I wish to separate them into 2000m intervals, 0-2000, 2000-4000, etc.  Once I have them separated I want to have a rose diagram of the orientations of the lines (faults) for each interval.  Faults are referring to faults as in geology...